# BigQuery cant import the data from DataPrep

Tags: google-bigquery, google-cloud-dataprep

I have the table created in BigQuery with partitioned by date and it has the Date type. DataPrep also has the same column with same data type. When i try to load the data from dataprep to bigquery table i am getting the error like  "The column datatypes in the dataset must match the destination column datatypes". Screenshot also been attached, please go through it and give me a solution.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9ognz.png)

Comment: I'm having the same problem, but I don't see the "Show columns that don't match" link appearing for me, I just get the error message. Does anyone know why this is?

Answer (score 0):

As the screenshot says, one is a `TIME`, `DATETIME`, or `TIMESTAMP`
the other is `STRING` as noted by the icons in front of your columns.

You need to make sure at dataset that you've chosen the right data type. Dataprep may infer wrong automatically sometimes your data type.

Comment: Hi, Thank you for your response. Please note in both bigquery and dataprep the type is Date only. I am also confused why the bigquery table shows string type as i have created the table with Date type only.

Comment: Even if the column type is Date, sometimes Dataprep takes as string, you can fix this when you edit your dataset import in Dataprep.

Comment: Problem is not with DataPrep, problem is with BigQuery as its not accepting it. While importing the data set dataPrep accepted this column as Date type only.

Answer (score 0):

In this [this thread](https://community.trifacta.com/s/question/0D51L00005M7sJ3SAJ/how-to-match-the-dataprep-data-types-to-bigquery-data-types) it is mentioned that you need to convert both types to `TIMESTAMP` in order to make this work. In my case this did the trick, but it is kind of cumbersome. Hopefully they will support this for simple `DATE` columns soon.